# Запятая при вводных словах

Tags: запятая

Нужна ли запятая после казалось бы или правильно так: В этой трудной, казалось бы невыносимой жизни, спасал всегда труд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этой трудной, казалось бы невыносимой жизни спасал всегда труд. Это вводное слово, но относится оно ко второму однородному определению, поэтому запятой не отделяется, чтобы не создать двусмысленности: казалось, что трудной, или казалось, что невыносимой. А вот после слова "жизни"запятая не нужна, потому что это не оборот,простое обстоятельство. Спасал где?- в этой трудной и невыносимой жизни.

Answer (score 2):

*§ 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня(Ч.).* -

так пишет Лопатин, следовательно:

В этой трудной, казалось невыносимой жизни спасал...

У Розенталя:

*При наличии однородных определений, когда может возникнуть сомнение, к какому из однородных членов предложения, предшествующему или последующему, относится находящееся между ними вводное слово, второе определение вместе с вводным словом может образовать уточняющую конструкцию: Эти сведения почерпнуты из нового, кажется специально для данного случая составленного, отчёта — без вводного слова между однородными определениями стояла бы запятая;*

Если следовать Розенталю, то:

В этой трудной, казалось невыносимой, жизни спасал...

Answer (score 1):

Вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота, запятая после ''казалось бы'' не требуется.

Корректно: В этой трудной, ***казалось невыносимой,*** жизни спасал ...

Comment: Здесь нет оборота - ни причастного, ни деепричастного, ни уточняющего. Если говорить об уточнении, то запятая стояла бы после прилагательного "невыносимой", это ведь оно уточняет,вернее усиливает, поясняет, потому что значение не сужается, но после определений она не ставится, получаются просто однородные члены.

Comment: Как раз, если прилагательное поясняет, то возможна запятая. Может, мне все-таки поставить запятую после "невыносимой"?

Comment: Здесь обособленное определение. Спасал в какой жизни? - невыносимой. А во-вторых , оборот с водным словом требуется закрыть. Иначе это уже будет не вводное слово. 

И еще:вы утверждаете, что здесь однородные члены и запятая не нужна. 
Но: При наличии однородных определений , когда может возникнуть сомнение к какому из них относится находящиеся вводное слово, второе определение вместе с вводным словом может образовать уточняющую конструкцию. : Эти сведения почерпнуты из нового, казалось специального для данного случая составленного ,отчета - без вводного слова между од/оп-и стояла бы запятая.

Comment: Ср.: В этой трудной, невыносимой жизни...

Comment: Я согласна с Вами.

Comment: Значит, я выделяю запятыми оборот "казалось бы невыносимой". Я правильно поняла?

Comment: См.: дополнение к основному ответу.

Comment: § 83. Пояснительные согласованные определения не выделяются, а лишь отделяются от поясняемого определения запятой. Пояснение возникает при особых по значению определениях — они имеют общий неконкретизированный, неопределенный смысл. Второе, поясняющее определение снимает неопределенность: Подснежники были особой, неодолимой страстью Славы (Бар.); Совсем другие, городские звуки слышались снаружи и внутри квартала (Кат.) (см. § 41).Но при отсутствии непосредственного контакта между  определениями поясняющее определение обособляется:Другое ложе, пустое, находилось с другой стороны стола (Булг.).

Comment: Этот параграф у Розенталя:
 § 24 п. 1 § 24 п. 5 § 24 п. 7
У Вас определения идут друг за другом - запятой нет

Comment: Вводное слово не считается, оно не относится к смыслу предложения, только указывает на предположительность одного из однородных определений

Comment: Людмила. в в вашем предложении нет вводного слова. А в данном примере есть. 
> При наличии однородных определений , когда может возникнуть сомнение к какому из них относится находящиеся вводное слово, второе определение вместе с вводным словом может образовать уточняющую конструкцию. : Эти сведения почерпнуты из нового, казалось специального для данного случая составленного ,отчета - без вводного слова между од/оп-и стояла бы запятая.

Comment: В данном случае может возникнуть сомнение: к какому определению относится вводное слово -к первому или ко второму.